# Prove existence of unique maximal solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to prove that $x'=t^2\sqrt{1+2x},~ x(0)=0$ has a unique maximal solution.

I thought of using that $\sqrt{1+2x}$ is bounded by a linear function, but the only theorem I know about that needs the function to be defined for all real x, which doesn't work here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aren't you allowed to integrate the ODE which is separable ?

Comment: Well, I found one by integrating: $x(t)=frac{t^6-9}{18}$. How do I know it's unique?

Comment: Nevermind, I know how. Thanks!

Comment: The solution you posted does not seem to be correct. May be you could add the solution of the problem in the post. This could be useful to other particiants. Cheers :-)